# AndroidViewClient does not show id

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I've been toying around with AndroidViewClient for a little while, but I don't get why this extension will not show the id of a view when running the dump.py example. My device is above API lvl 16. What could be the problem?

I get an output like this, but again I don't know why it can't tell the name of the views...

```
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1
   android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3
         android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/4
            android.widget.Button id/no_id/5 New Jersey
            android.widget.Button id/no_id/6 New York
            android.widget.Button id/no_id/7 New Castle
            android.widget.Button id/no_id/8 New Berg
            android.widget.Button id/no_id/9 New Class
```

Error:

```
   C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro
idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
] Script terminated due to an exception
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\e
xamples\dump.py", line 87, in <module>
    vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1), **kwargs2)
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\s
rc\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 935, in __init__
    adb = ViewClient.__obtainAdbPath()
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\s
rc\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1075, in _ViewClient__obtainAdbPath

    raise Exception('adb="%s" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_H
OME in the environment?' % adb)
Exception: adb="adb.exe" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_HOME i
n the environment?

130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:219)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1159)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1163)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1167)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py._ViewClient__obtainAdbPath$56(C:\A
ndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmil
ano\android\viewclient.py:1075)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient
-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\view
client.py)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:117)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:307)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.__init__$54(C:\AndroidViewClient-m
aster\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewcl
ient.py:1020)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient
-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\view
client.py)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:191)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:385)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:380)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java:120)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(PyClass.java:194)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:537)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewCl
ient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py:89)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\And
roidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156
)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.
java:77)
130428 20:11:28.636:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter
.java:189)
```

Answer (score 3):

If device's **API** level is **>= 16** the default backend used by [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) is **UiAutomator** which does not show the IDs. To provide an extra level of help AndroidViewClient assigns unique IDs to the Views, and this is what `dump.py` is showing in your case.

[image: androidviewclient activity diagram]

You can force **ViewServer** backend by providing the corresponding command line option to `dump.py`:

```
$ dmup.py --force-view-server-use
```

and you will get View ID's.

Comment: Hmm... thought that would do the trick, but if I add force view server, it gives me an error.

Comment: Also, `dump.py` works, but `dump.py --force-view-server-use` does not.

Comment: It seems to be a Windows problem: `Cannot run program "C:\Windows\system32\adb.exe"`. Unfortunately I don't use Windows so cannot reproduce. Anyway, the problem may have been fixed by latest version (2.3.14). Give it a try and update your question if necessary.

Comment: Hmm... I just downloaded the newest version, but now dump.py won't even work. I updated my error. It's asking for a new environment variable which I don't see in the wiki.